# R ggplot vary line thickness or style based on conditional

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is [a link to a .csv of my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zzbgxrqe30th4t/pop_c.csv?dl=0), which I call "pop_c".

I generate a line plot using the following code:

```
ggplot(data = pop_c, aes(x = year, y = pop_change, color = state)) + 
  geom_line(stat="identity")
```

However, I would like to vary either the line's thickness, style, or shading based on the 'recession' column. If the value in the 'recession' column is 1, I'd like the line to be either: a) thicker, b) shaded darker, or c) some combination of the two.

Can someone explain how to vary a line's thickness, style, and/or shading based on such a conditional?

Comment: add `alpha=recession` or `size=recession` or `linetype=recession` into `aes()`

Comment: @moman822 Perfect. This R newbie thanks you!

Comment: You're welcome! I've added it as an answer so you can mark it correct

Comment: Quick comment: I was searching for a solution for a similar problem, and found this. Since the OP did not add the data structure (at least the headers), and the original data is not available, it wasn't very helpful... is it possible to have at least the description of the data frame to see how the solution works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `alpha=recession` or `size=recession` or `linetype=recession` into `aes()`